# Video stream recorder through JMeter

Tags: jmeter, video-streaming

I would like to know is it possible to do video stream record using JMeter. Since i was recording few scenario and got stuck when it comes to start video and play.

Please let me know if i need to do some setting changes/ any links that explains the same.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) can only record [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) or [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) protocols, it will be able to "record" the video only if it's delivered via [HTTP GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) request, otherwise JMeter won't recognise the traffic.

Depending on the nature of your video you might be able to use [JMeter HLS Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/HLS-3.0-Release) to replicate the real user watching the movie network traffic footprint